# Object diagram with infinite number of objects

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Some time ago I found an example of a class diagram (with a finite number of classes) so that any object diagram can be derived only with an infinite number of objects. I tried searching for this case, but couldn't find it. I don't think that such diagrams have any practical use, but I found it fascinating, because from university I thought that this isn't possible.

Can you give an example of a class diagram such that any object diagram will require an infinite number of objects?

Comment: Actually I don't get what you are looking for.

Comment: Create a class diagram with such associations so that we always need an infinite number of objects for an object diagram

Comment: Well, there is no infinite number of objects. We are living in a finite world (though it's rather big). You make a model for the reality. Infinity is for mathematics. You don't use UML for mathematics.

Comment: I suspect it was a recursive association. This could be used to represent a case with an infinity of objects IN THEORY. But this does not require an infinity of objects, whereas a normal association between two classes could also lead to an infinity of objects IN THEORY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest example I can think of:

[image: composite with at least one part]

Since every `Thing` must have at least one `part`, the chain of parts goes on to infinity. There can be no loops in this chain, because

> UML 2.5.1: Compositions may be linked in a directed *acyclic* graph

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a class diagram that models an infinite number of instances:

[image: Class-diagram-infinite-objects]

This class diagram models an infinite chain of atoms.

The constraint is required, otherwise it would be possible to have a ring of atoms.